# WCF Client: Limit calls to BeginGetX until EndGetX is called

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, mutex

In my winforms client application, I have generated asynchronous methods for my WCF service (Begin... and End...).

When the application starts, it makes async calls to the server to get and cache data that will be later used in the application (e.g. list of countries).

If the application's main thread requires this data (e.g. to fill a combobox) before the async call had a chance to complete, I would like to block the main thread until the async call had Ended. I want to avoid making redundant calls to the WCF server.

I have tried to use a Monitor/Mutex and called `Monitor.Enter(countryLock)` then `BeginGetCountries` in the main thread and `Monitor.Exit(countryLock)` when the `EndGetCountries` method is called. However, I am facing the following exception:

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Am I supposed to call `Monitor.Exit(...)` on the same thread that called `Monitor.Enter(...)`?  If yes, how can I know the owner of the `Monitor` object and make a call in its context?

Comment: If you need a sync endpoint in some contexts why not implement one?  Are you in control of your service?

Comment: I do not mind multiple clients calling the same method at the same time.  I would like to limit a single client from asking for the same data twice, the client will try to load the data async ahead of time. However, if the client requires the data immediately and does not find it cached, it will go ask for it not knowing that it is on its way.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want really to block the main thread.  What you want to do is set a flag that the operation is pending and disable parts of your UI that depend on the result.  When the result is returned from the asynchronous WCF operation, you can enable those parts of the UI and populate the data.

*if* you block the main thread it will give the appearance that the application has halted and that will be a poor experience for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter Richie said, you don't want to lock in your UI thread. A "busy" flag is all you need, really.

Secondly, trying to do this with Monitor.Enter like you describe would not work, as the same thread is allowed to enter the same monitor twice without blocking.

And if you do lock, then yes, you are supposed to call Monitor.Exit(...) on the same thread that called Monitor.Enter(...). If that was the only only problem, you could marshal this back to the UI thread with this.BeginInvoke(). But like I said, locking with Monitor in a single threaded scenario makes no sense.